# illegal_argument_exception Invalid JSON in payload for OpenSearch ingestion pipeline though model/_predict is working

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have deployed a text embedding model in AWS OpenSearch using a connector. The following request in Dev Tools returns a valid response with embedding.

```
POST /_plugins/_ml/models/<model_id>/_predict
{
  "parameters": {
    "inputs": ["hello"]
  }
}
```

like so

```
{
  "inference_results": [
    {
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "response",
          "dataAsMap": {
            "embedding": [
              0.18129970133304596,
              -0.05622033402323723, ...
```

However, when I simulate inserting a doc using my ingest pipeline that runs on this model, like so

```
POST /_ingest/pipeline/nlp-ingest-pipeline/_simulate?verbose=true
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "product-index",
      "_id": "1",
      "_source":{
        "product_text": "hello"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get an error (shortened)

```
            "root_cause": [
              {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Invalid JSON in payload"
              }
            ],
```

This is the pipeline processor

```
"processors": [
    {
      "text_embedding": {
        "model_id": "<model_id>",
        "field_map": {
          "product_text": "product_embedding"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I suspect the pipeline is not able to parse my model endpoint response. Where to see the ingest pipeline's interface to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The ingest pipeline expects the model response of the form**

```json
{
  "inference_results": [
    {
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "sentence_embedding",
          "data_type": "FLOAT32",
          "shape": [
            768
          ],
          "data": [
            0.18129970133304596, ...
          ], ...
```

This can be achieved by using `pre_process_function` and `post_process_function` in the [Connector API](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/ml-commons-plugin/remote-models/blueprints/#built-in-pre--and-post-processing-functions). These functions are written in [Painless scripting language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-guide.html).

I use the following, as seen in the reference blog post.

```json
"actions": [
      {
         "action_type": "predict",
         "method": "POST",
         "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
         },
         "url": "<inference_url>",
         "pre_process_function": "\n    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();\n    builder.append(\"\\\"\");\n    String first = params.text_docs[0];\n    builder.append(first);\n    builder.append(\"\\\"\");\n    def parameters = \"{\" +\"\\\"inputs\\\":[\" + builder + \"]}\";\n    return  \"{\" +\"\\\"parameters\\\":\" + parameters + \"}\";",
         "post_process_function": "\n      def name = \"sentence_embedding\";\n      def dataType = \"FLOAT32\";\n      if (params.<YOUR ENDPOINT JSON OUTPUT LABEL> == null || params.<YOUR ENDPOINT JSON OUTPUT LABEL>.length == 0) {\n        return params.message;\n      }\n      def shape = [params.<YOUR ENDPOINT JSON OUTPUT LABEL>.length];\n      def json = \"{\" +\n                 \"\\\"name\\\":\\\"\" + name + \"\\\",\" +\n                 \"\\\"data_type\\\":\\\"\" + dataType + \"\\\",\" +\n                 \"\\\"shape\\\":\" + shape + \",\" +\n                 \"\\\"data\\\":\" + params.<YOUR ENDPOINT JSON OUTPUT LABEL> +\n                 \"}\";\n      return json;\n    ",
         "request_body": "{\"inputs\": ${parameters.inputs}}"
      }
   ]
```

Since my inference endpoint returns `{"embedding": [...]}`, I use `embedding` in the place of `<YOUR ENDPOINT JSON OUTPUT LABEL>`.

---

### Additional context

My sample payload for `model/_predict` is

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "inputs": ["hello"]
  }
}
```

Reference - [AWS Community Blog](https://community.aws/content/2ZVEF1vMg0Jh2IwtbVMEVEMND59/developing-neural-searches-with-custom-models?lang=en)